# why editText make program stopped if didn't input anything

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I new. I have 2 editText and 1 TextView, 1 button. I want to sum from 2 input. Its success if I input all editText. But if I didn't input, the aplication stopped.

```
package panda.c;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;




public class calculate extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

EditText input1,input2;
Button sum;
TextView total;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.calcu);

input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1);
input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input2);
total = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total);
sum = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sum);
sum.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {

int inputt1 = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText().toString());
int inputt2 = Integer.parseInt(input2.getText().toString());

switch (v.getId()) {                    
case R.id.sum:

sum.setText(Integer.toString(inputt1+inputt2));

break;
default:
break;
}}}
```

I didn't input anything. I just clicked sum, and then the program stopped. But if I input all editText, I clicked sum, Its work. why? I want if I do not input, and click sum, the application still run.

Comment: can you post your logcat error?

Comment: nothing error.. @JackTurkey , I typo sum.setText(Integer.toString(inputt1+inputt2)); , but still if I do not input anything, program stopped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code fragment in you OnClick() method could be the following:

```
int inputt1 = 0;
int inputt2 = 0;
try {
    inputt1 = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText().toString());
    inputt2 = Integer.parseInt(input2.getText().toString());
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
//notify the user here somehow or just leave empty
//or just return, if you don't want to sum default values
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's called a `NullPointerException`. You're trying to parse `null` to `integer`. You need to enclose the parsing statements in a `try` block and `catch` the `NullPointerException` and set some default value to `inputt1` and `inputt2` or notify the user to put some value with a `Toast`.

**Correction**

It's not a `NullPointerException` it's a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: to add an additional info bit: on the lines where you get the text from the `EditText` you automatically try and parse them. you should check for `null` values first, and only if the input is not `null` you'll be able to parse the Integer from it.

Comment: Correction: NumberFormatException is raised

Comment: I understand. But cant to.. hehehe

Answer (score 2):

It's because if a field is left blank, Integer.parseInt() will fail. You should set a default value of 0 if the field is left blank so it won't force close.

Here's a simple solution to check if it's empty and use 0 as default:

```
int inputt1 = input1.getText().toString().equals("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(input1.getText().toString());
int inputt2 = input2.getText().toString().equals("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(input2.getText().toString());
```

Also, set `android:inputType="number"` to your `EditText` so you it will restrict input to numbers only.

Edit: Updated code to make it compatible to all API levels.

Comment: error - The method isEmpty() is undefined for the 
  type String . @Krauxe

Comment: My bad, `isEmpty()` was added in API level 9, so using it on lower API levels will give an error. You can use `input1.getText().toString().equals("")` instead. See updated answer.

Comment: error. hehe Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to int @Krauxe

Comment: You have a typo in your code. The code I posted is correct, it's how a ternary operator/expression is used. You are probably terminating it prematurely, hence assigning the `boolean` part instead of the 2 possible `int` values.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `Integer.parseInt()` and parsing `""` inside it. This will definetly give you NumberFormat Exception.

Try this...

```
if(!(input1.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))){
inputt1 = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText().toString());
}
```

same for the other input as well..

Hope this helps,..

Comment: Better to catch NumberFormatException. This wil handle all parsing errors not only empty string and in single piece of code for both input fields. This is what exception-handling is made for.